# Transform Parameterized Type (With Inferred Parameter)

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, typeclass, parameterized, abstract-data-type

I have a data type which carries a 'hidden' (inferred) type and a concrete value. Now I try to implement a function which changes both of these but am unable to make it pass GHC.

My sample code is this:

```
data T tag val = T val

data A = A
data B = B

mkIntVal :: T a b -> T Int b
mkIntVal (T x) = T x

mkCharVal :: T a b -> T Char b
mkCharVal (T x) = T x

convert :: T Int a -> T Char b
convert (T A) = mkCharVal $ T B
convert (T B) = mkCharVal $ T A
```

The error it produces is this:

```
test.hs:13:12:
    Couldn't match type `A' with `B'
    In the pattern: A
    In the pattern: T A
    In an equation for `convert': convert (T A) = mkCharVal $ T B

test.hs:13:17:
    Couldn't match type `B' with `A'
    Expected type: T Char b
      Actual type: T Char B
    In the expression: mkCharVal $ T B
    In an equation for `convert': convert (T A) = mkCharVal $ T B
```

What has to be done to make this work? Do I have to change the data structure?

---

## EDIT

I am trying to extend `Don Stewart`'s solution to work with polymorphic data types. I have been playing around with the instance definition but the most promising looking a came up with is this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

data C a = C a deriving Show

class Convertable inVal outVal outTag | outVal -> outTag where
    convert :: T Int inVal -> T outTag outVal

instance Convertable A B Char where
    convert (T A) = mkCharVal $ T B

instance Convertable B A Char where
    convert (T B) = mkCharVal $ T A

instance Convertable a b Char => Convertable (C a) (C (T Char b)) Char where
    convert (T (C val)) = mkCharVal $ T (C (convert val)) -- line 29
```

But That gives me just another error message:

```
test.hs:29:57:
    Could not deduce (a ~ T Int inVal0)
    from the context (Convertable a b Char)
      bound by the instance declaration at test.hs:28:10-70
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at test.hs:28:22
    In the first argument of `convert', namely `val'
    In the first argument of `C', namely `(convert val)'
    In the first argument of `T', namely `(C (convert val))'
```

As Don says it should be possible I'm interested in how that would be implemented.

---

## Solution

After a lot more 'playing' I finally came up with something that works. Does this look good to you?

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}


data T tag val = T val deriving Show

data A = A deriving Show
data B = B deriving Show
data C a = C a deriving Show


class Convertable inTag inVal outTag outVal | inTag -> outTag, inVal -> outVal
where
    convert :: T inTag inVal -> T outTag outVal

instance Convertable Int A Char B where
    convert (T A) = T B

instance Convertable Int B Char A where
    convert (T B) = T A

instance (Convertable Int (T Int a) Char (T Char b), Convertable Int a Char b)
    => Convertable Int (C (T Int a)) Char (C (T Char b)) where
    convert (T (C x)) = T (C (convert x))

instance Convertable Int (C (T Int A)) Char (C (T Char B)) where
    convert (T (C x)) = T (C (convert x))

instance Convertable Int (C (T Int B)) Char (C (T Char A)) where
    convert (T (C x)) = T (C (convert x))
```

Usage:

```
*Main> convert $ mkIntVal $ T $ C $ mkIntVal $ T A
T (C (T B))
*Main> :t it
it :: T Char (C (T Char B))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each case of your `convert` function has a different, conflicting type:

```
convertA :: T t A -> T Char B
convertA (T A) = mkCharVal $ T B

convertB :: T t B -> T Char A
convertB (T B) = mkCharVal $ T A
```

You can unify these via a typeclass,

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}


class C a b c | b -> c where
    convert :: T t a -> T c b

instance C A B Char where
    convert (T A) = mkCharVal (T B)

instance C B A Char where
    convert (T B) = mkCharVal (T A)
```

if you truly wish a single function that at different types, converts in different directions. Note how this takes any `T` with a tag, discards it, and replaces the tag and value with a new tag determined by the value type.

Comment: Now I understand what was wrong with my attempt. Would it be possible at a later point to extend this solution to polymorphic result types or is it restricted to 'normal' types? As I wouldn't have any concrete value to put in the instance definition I don't know how I would go for a function like `convert (T (C val)) = mkCharVal $ T (C (convert val))`